# Wouldn't the function crash if i pass head to be null and k to be any positive integer?

Tags: c, linked-list

the following is a function that reverses elements of a link list k elements at a time,
My question is whether the function could crash if i were to pass null as head, because, next is never initialized to any value in this case and since it may be pointing to a garbage value, the if(next!= null) may be satisfied, so the statement head->next can be executed, when head is actually null, causing the program to crash?

```
struct node *reverse (struct node *head, int k)
{
    struct node* current = head;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev = NULL;
    int count = 0;   

    /*reverse first k nodes of the linked list */
    while (current != NULL && count < k)
    {
       next  = current->next;
       current->next = prev;
       prev = current;
       current = next;
       count++;
    }

    /* next is now a pointer to (k+1)th node 
       Recursively call for the list starting from current.
       And make rest of the list as next of first node */
    if(next !=  NULL)
    {  head->next = reverse(next, k); }

    /* prev is new head of the input list */
    return prev;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass head as `NULL`, you skip the while loop, and the statement `if(next !=  NULL)`would compare an uninitialized pointer to NULL, which is undefined behavior.
So yes, your program could crash.

What an unitialized pointer contains is not specified, and is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The strict answer to your quesion is: no, not likely.

Given `head == 0` and `k > 0`, you'll end up at line 21 in your function with `next != 0` (most likely) but with some garbage random value (as you pointed out) that will be used for your recursive call.

Your code may very well not crash the first time through, but it's very likely to crash at some point, or continue to recurse for some unknown time.  In any event, you won't get the results you expect.